# MySQL Users Table Show A 'Ghost' Account as well as Multiple Root Accounts

Tags: mysql, database

I was able to configure three instances of MySQL 5.6.16 win32. I have a **XAMPP MySQL** installation, and I have two **no-install MySQL** installation.

Today, I decided to create two users -besides my root account- for my **ColdFusion 9** data driven applications. As soon as I started examining the Users table, I noticed a couple of anomalies. I noticed three **root accounts**, as well as a very strange empty space. The other two accounts listed are the newly created users.

I'm aware that this might be obvious because I have three MySQL installations. But, I have the **MySQL** installations in separate directories. Do MySQL accounts usually propagate in other existing installations or this is not normal?

I have reconstructed the issue below:

```
mysql> SELECT User FROM mysql.user;
    +-----------+
    | User      |
    +-----------+
    |user001jh  |
    |root       |
    |root       |
    |           |
    |root       |
    |user000jh  |
    +-----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Cross-site duplicate for the three *root* users: [MySQL log shows 3 root users, 2 without passwords? Why?](http://serverfault.com/questions/235593/mysql-log-shows-3-root-users-2-without-passwords-why)